# Joining a Selenium Browser Session in VBA which the browser is already open

Tags: vba, selenium, ms-access, selenium-webdriver

I have run into a snag.  I can't find any documentation in VBA on how to attach to an already open web browser.  I have found solutions for this problem in Java, but not VBA. I am programming automation in Microsoft Access and am using VBA for my current project which is why I need a VBA solution.

Using Selenium EdgeDriver or chromedriver I am able to successfully open a web page and control it just fine. The problem is I need to access this page multiple times and if I login too often I get hit with a captcha.  I have identified a method of determining the SessionID in VBA as well as the Driver IP address, but can’t figure out how to reconnect successfully to the previous session.  If someone could help here I would be very grateful.

Thanks,

Andrew